# How to iterate through each orderID to show the associated customer details (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show all the orders from my Orders table, but I need to match the UserID which is in both my Orders and Users table so I can display the correct user information next to each orderID.

At the moment this only displays 1 row of data, (the first orderID).

How can I make this iterate through each orderID instead of just returning the first orderID?

```
<?php

     // select all from Orders table
     if ($result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Orders"))
     {
     // fetch the resulting array
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        // extract the array
           extract($row);

           // select all from Users table where userID = userID from the Orders table
           if ($result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userID='$userID'"))
           {
           // fetch the resulting array
           while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)or die(mysql_error()))
            {
            // extract the array
                extract($row2);
                //display the order details
                echo "<p><b>Order:</b> $orderID: $firstname $surname $address</p>";
            }

           }
        }
     }

     mysql_close($conn);

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the UserID in both tables there's no problem since each user then will be unique (at least I assume that they are). So you could try:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Orders O, Users U WHERE O.UserID = U.UserID AND U.UserID = '$UserID'";
```

Then you can iterate through the result which will contain the order information and the user information :)

```
   $result =mysql_query($query);

   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)or die(mysql_error()))
    {
    // extract the array
        extract($row);
        //display the order details
        echo "<p><b>Order:</b> $orderID: $firstname $surname $address</p>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the query looks fine however now it doesn't echo any information (even the html parts). What could be the problem?

Comment: try to write out the mysql result from the row-array like: echo $row[0]; echo $row[1]; and so on for all the different attributes you have fetched from the table (you can try with just echo row[0]; in the beginning) and check if you get any result printed on the screen.